# storing data twice in ODE solver using R

Tags: r, file, ode

Please check the following code, I am wondering why it is storing data values twice in file "LV.txt". Here is the code followed by snippet of "LV.txt" file. Also, why time is not like 0, 0.1, 0.2, ......?

```
library(deSolve)

unlink("LV.txt")
predpreyLV<-function(t,y,p){
   N<-y[1]
   P<-y[2]

   write(paste0(t,"  ",N,"  ",P),"LV.txt",append=TRUE)

   with(as.list(p),{
      dNdt<- r*N*(1-(N/1000))-a*P*N
      dPdt<- -b*P+f*P*N
      return(list(c(dNdt,dPdt)))
  })
}

r<-0.5; a<-0.01; f<-0.01; b<-0.2;

p<-c(r=r,a=a, b=b, f=f)
y0<-c(N=25, P=5)
times<-seq(0,1000,0.1)
LV.out<-ode(y=y0,times,predpreyLV, p)
```

In FILE:

```
0  25  5
0  25  5
9.99116343466594e-05  25.0010927835007  5.00002497790859
9.99116343466594e-05  25.0010928292789  5.00002498349248
0.000199823268693319  25.0021856585615  5.00004996698548
0.000199823268693319  25.0021857043414  5.00004997256968
0.0412995612856433  25.4556252934873  5.01080199665104
0.0412995612856433  25.4556535740967  5.010807466621
```

Comment: Can you explain more fully what you are seeing that makes you ask: "why it is storing data values twice in file "LV.txt"?

Comment: I am using write(paste0(t,"  ",N,"  ",P),"LV.txt",append=TRUE) in my code which stores it twice in a file such as 0  25  5; 0  25  5

Comment: Anyone can explain this please.

Comment: I think you are expecting too much mind-reading ability on our part. I see no variable named `time` and I'm only seeing duplications in the first two rows and in the first column. You haven't explained why that should not be the result. Seems like you would expect a gradient based algorithm in 2 dimensions, as it appears you are modeling, to first calculate a x-gradient and then calculate a y-gradient at each point. Mind you this is just a guess.

Comment: Would it help to suggest reading the manual to address the "time"-question?: `The return value of 'func' should be a list, whose first element is a vector containing the derivatives of y with respect to time, and whose next elements are global values that are required at each point in times. The derivatives must be specified in the same order as the state "variables y."`  So doesn't appear to me that the first elements returned are supposed to be items from the `times` argument.

Comment: I am trying to solve a system of D.E. (lotka-Volterra). In last 5 lines of code I defined necessary variables. times variable is defined in 2nd last line of the code, which contains the time at which values of unknown are required. The predpreyLV function defines right side function of the derivatives. What I am trying to achieve here is to check the outcome at every point of time before it finishes simulation. My actual program takes about 4 hours to complete and the only time I can check solution is at the end of simulation.

Comment: (continue from above)  I inserted write(…) inside predpreyLV and expecting unknown values at previous time. Is there any way, I can save data in a file before completing simulations.

Comment: I'll bet the reason it takes 4 hours is mostly because of all those `write` calls. Have you tried the verbose=TRUE option or looking at the `diagnostics` functions?

Comment: The program I posted is just to mimic the original problem. Original program contains 5 D.E and without write(...) statement.

Comment: hmmm, I think i got the answer. For calculating unknowns at time t=t0, there are two functional calls and which make sense to me. SO this write(...) will not produce the answer that I am looking for. Now I am back to square one. I am trying to find, how can I save data values at each time step during simulation. For example at t=0, 0.1, 0.2 ...

Comment: Look at `LV.out`. Doesn't that contain the model solution at each specified time (e.g., t = 0, 0.1, 0.2...)? And you shouldn't try to output the solution while the ODE integrator is solving the equation, as this may not necessarily be the actual solution. For example, see [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-dynamic-models/2013q4/000280.html) where one of the authors for these packages explains that "Sometimes, considerable work is needed to identify a good automatic
stepping and sometimes, steps are discarded and the solver goes a little
bit back."

Comment: Yes, LV.out contains solution when it passes this line. I would like to know, is there any possibility to check the partial solution while it is working.